# reverse-i-search of history not finding expected commands

Tags: bash, history

Today upon bringing up a bash terminal I tried finding a frequently-used command from my bash history via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>. To my surprise, it wasn't found. Upon inspecting `~/.bash_history`, I saw instances of the command on several lines. Does the command history not work by checking the file, either in real time or against a cached copy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out there was a little more nuance than I was aware of: `HISTFILESIZE` determines the maximum number of lines saved in `.bash_history`, while `HISTSIZE` determines the number of lines from `~/.bash_history` loaded into a searchable cache. Upon increasing `HISTSIZE` to match `HISTFILESIZE`, I was able to find the command via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for posting this Q&A. I hope this clear demonstration of the interaction of these variables will help others too.

Comment: It actually started as just a Q, but a few more minutes of digging yielded an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from this (HISTFILESIZE), there is one reason why a line won't appear in history: A leading space. If you start a command with a space in the front like this:

`$ ls -l`

`$  ls -l` (extra space at the beginning)

then the latter won't show up in history. Related, here is what my .bashrc looks like:

```
.bashrc:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
.bashrc:export HISTSIZE=100000
.bashrc:export HISTFILESIZE=100000
.bashrc:export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
.bashrc:export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%d/%m/%y %T "
```

HTH