# Reverse search fails when commands are present in bash_history

Tags: bashrc, search, bash-history

Ubuntu 22.04, from terminal I type ctrl+r and `mosquitto_sub` it finds `mosquitto_sub --help` and nothing else. But:

```
# cat .bash_history | grep mosquitto_sub
mosquitto_sub --help
mosquitto_sub -t foo1/# -v
mosquitto_sub -t /# -v -u user -P <password>
mosquitto_sub -t /# -v -u user -P <password> -d
mosquitto_sub -t /# -v -u user -P <password> -d
mosquitto_sub -t /# -v -u user -P <password> -d -h localhost
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -u user -P <password> -d -h localhost
mosquitto_sub 
cat ~/.bash_history | grep mosquitto_sub
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -d
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -d -u user -P <password>
mosquitto_sub --help
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -d -u user -P <password> -c
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -d -u user -P <password> -c foo
mosquitto_sub -t '#' -v -d -u user -P <password>
```

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276919/reverse-i-search-of-history-not-finding-expected-commands) I read the problem can be related to the `bashrc` settings, mine are:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:ignorespace
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000
```

and:

```
# wc -l .bash_history 
244 .bash_history
```

well below the limits above.
Even ignoring the duplicates it should find other lines as well.

Comment: possible dupe https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276919/reverse-i-search-of-history-not-finding-expected-commands

Comment: @graham this is the question I've linked in my post! And as I explained I don't think it applies here. If I'm wrong, please tell me where

Comment: @muru, 1. why do you think I have *two* `.bash_history` files? 2. `HISTFILE` is `/root/.bash_history` as expected. 3. Yes, `history` contains the commands

Comment: @muru, I apologize but I don't understand. WHERE did I show two files?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood the `cat ~/.bash_history | grep mosquitto_sub` line as a new command with output following it. I'll delete my comments.